# Adding a emoji reaction to command line in discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want the bot reacting to my command line. For example: *-suggest suggestion* < i want to add a thumb up emoji to that sentence. I already know how to add reactions to the outcome of command but i have no idea how to react to the command line

i got this simple suggest command and it gives now a reaction to the outcome of the command:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.user)
async def suggest(ctx,*, suggestion):
    channel = client.get_channel(754640430670413835)
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x55f7b1, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)
    embed.set_author(name="{}".format(ctx.author),icon_url="{}".format(ctx.author.avatar_url))
    embed.add_field(name="Suggestion:", value="{}".format(suggestion), inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="{}.".format(ctx.author))
    embed1 = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    emoji1 = '\N{THUMBS DOWN SIGN}'
    emoji2 = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
    await embed1.add_reaction(emoji2)
    await embed1.add_reaction(emoji1)
    await ctx.send("Thank you for your suggestion {}".format(ctx.author.mention)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Please be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctx.message` is what you are looking for (command message) then add the wanted reactions to that.

For example:

```py
await ctx.message.add_reaction("✅")
```